# Django : Two ways of caching template : What is the difference?

Tags: django, templates, caching

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader

Here we have "cached.Loader" to cache template

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching

And we also have "Template fragment caching"

I know the latter allows a finer control over which parts to cache. But if I enable both, will it consume double amount of memory for same fragments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django template engine has basically three steps to perform:

- load the template file from the filesystem
- compile the template code into python
- execute the code to output plain text (usually HTML markup).

The `cached.Loader` caches only the two first steps : your templates wont be loaded and compiled every time, but will be executed. This is faster and usually safe as long as you are using thread safe template tags.

The fragments caching mecanism caches the final output : the (static) HTML markup ready to be rendered to users.

So if you need to render an already cached template fragment, no calculation will be made other than retrieving the final output from your cache engine.

As you are now serving static, pre-computed content, it's up to you to ensure that the right data are served to the right user: each fragment may be cached per user, language, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The two caching mechanisms are not equivalent.

The template fragment caching caches the rendered template, so if you visited this page first,

```
{% cache 500 welcome %}
Hello, {{ name }}
{% endcache %}
```

and then I visited it after you, Then I would also see 'Hello timkung'.

This isn't a problem with the cached template loader. It caches the compiled template in memory, which saves Django from fetching the file from the disk and compiling it for every request. However, the template is still rendered once for every request.

Note that the template fragment caching does not necessarily store the keys in memory, it depends which cache you are using (e.g. Memcached, db, file, ...)

You can use both of these techniques together, you just need to be a bit careful with template caching when you are displaying different content to different users.

Comment: Docs mention that in such cases you use tag like this: {% cache 500 sidebar request.user.username %}, see "Template fragment caching" in django docs.

Answer (score 2):

> By default, the templating system will read and compile your templates every time they need to be rendered. While the Django templating system is quite fast, the overhead from reading and compiling templates can add up.

That means even if you use template fragment caching to cache the output of one of your template fragments, you're still compiling the templates every time. i.e. `every_time_you_render = template.Template('template')`.

The cached loader stores one instance in memory.

Template fragment caching is just an in-template cache mechanism to compute the output of its contents and cache it instead of re-rendering that block.

The two solve completely different problems. For example on one of my sites.. I did notice that compiling my templates (which had a lot of user driven dynamic includes) was taking up a ton of time. The cached loader saves the day here.

If on the other hand, the computation inside the templates is your bottleneck, then fragment caching or page caching in general would be more useful.